# How to scrape elements from a HTML Dygraph?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, dygraphs

I'm trying to fetch all the datapoints from this website https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactions.html using BeautifulSoup and requests in Python. So far I have the code:

```
session = requests.Session()
page = session.get(https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactions.html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
values = soup.find_all('script')[4]
```

this returns the section of html code that all the data points are in, but the data points are a part of a Dygraph and I don't know how to get them. I also tried

```
values = soup.find_all('script')[4].get_text()
```

but that doesn't return anything at all.

```
d = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("container"),[[new Date("2009/01/03"),null],[new Date("2009/01/04"),null],
[new Date("2009/01/05"),null],[new Date("2009/01/06"),null],[new Date("2009/01/07"),null],
[new Date("2009/01/08"),null],[new Date("2009/01/09"),null],[new Date("2009/01/10"),null],
[new Date("2009/01/11"),null],[new Date("2009/01/12"),7]........etc
```

On the website code the data looks like this, but i'm not familiar with what this means and how I get this data. I don't know what the double brackets at the beginning and end of the dataset represent.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand the problem

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = dict()
session = requests.Session()
page = session.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactions.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
values = str(soup.find_all('script')[4])
values = values.split('d = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("container"),')[1].split(', {labels: ')[0]
for i in range(values.count('new Date')):
    date = values.split('new Date("')[i+1].split('"')[0]
    value = values.split('"),')[i+1].split(']')[0]
    print(date, value)
```

this?

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to pull the data out of the script. I don't know if the following method is what you want.

```
from simplified_scrapy import utils, SimplifiedDoc, req
html = req.get(
    'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactions.html')

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
js = doc.getElementByText('new Dygraph', tag='script').html
js = js[js.find('document.getElementById("container"),') +
        len('document.getElementById("container"),'):]
js = js[:js.find(', {labels:')] # Get data part
js = js.replace('[new Date("', '').replace('")', '')[1:-2]
data = [kv.split(',') for kv in js.split('],')]
print(data)
```

Result:

```
[['2009/01/03', 'null'], ['2009/01/04', 'null'], ['2009/01/05', 'null'], ['2009/01/06', 'null'], ['2009/01/07', 'null'], ['2009/01/08', 'null'], ['2009/01/09', 'null'], ...
```